# Select elements from XML using Xpath

Tags: xml, eclipse, xpath, jet, emf

I have a huge XML file. Looks somthing like the following

```
<component name='comp1'>
  <child> ... </child>
  <child> ... </child>
  <optional id='1'> ... </optional>
</component>

<component name='comp2'>
  <child> ... </child>
  <child> ... </child>
  <optional id='1'> ... </optional>  
  <optional id='1'> ... </optional>
  <optional id='2'> ... </optional>
</component>
```

I want to select optional elements based on their ids from each component without repeating any id within the same component.

Simply, I want the following output for comp2, for example:

```
Comp2
1
2
```

My problem is to select optional elements that has similar id one time only.

I am using Xpath with JET1 (java Emitter Template)
I am iterating each component looking for optional elements and printing their text(). However, my loop is resulting in the following

```
 Comp2
    1
    1
    2
```

I want to eliminate duplicated results.

My JET temple:

```
<c:iterate select="//component/optional" var="Optional">
<c:get select="$Optional"/>
</c:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//component/optional[not(@id = following-sibling::optional/@id)]
```

Comment: We don't know how big "huge" is (it could mean anything from 1Mb to 100Gb), but whatever it means, it means that a solution with O(n^2) performance is not a good idea. I'm afraid I can't offer a solution of my own because I don't know JET.

Comment: "$currComp//optional/guard/booleanExp/equals/symbol

This is the path to the last element I want to extract without duplication. It's a text element with no attributes. so How can I include it in your provided XPath?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what JET supports, but believe that this **XPath 2.0 expression may give you a good idea for a solution in your case**:

```
/*/component[@name eq 'comp2']/optional
             [not(@id eq preceding-sibling::*[1][self::optional]/@id)]
                                                              /@id/string()
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated having this current document**:

```
<t>
    <component name='comp1'>
        <child> ... </child>
        <child> ... </child>
        <optional id='1'> ... </optional>
    </component>
    <component name='comp2'>
        <child> ... </child>
        <child> ... </child>
        <optional id='1'> ... </optional>
        <optional id='1'> ... </optional>
        <optional id='2'> ... </optional>
    </component>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
1 2
```

The time complexity for evaluating this XPath expression is only linear ( O(N) ) and **not** quadratic ( O(N^2) )

Comment: Thanks. But JET uses Xpath 1. I'm not sure if this will work. Plus, What if the id attribute is a child element of optional? and not included as an attribute?
I tired  //component/optional/text() but nothing again!

Comment: @607-GXF, You seem confused about what is the format of the source XML document -- you need to clarify this, before asking a question, or the question is less meaningful. As for XPath2 -- it is very easily translated to a few XPath 1.0 expressions (just replace `eq` with `=`, and also have getting the string value of the attributes in a second step)that you have to execute and link together in a meaningful way using your Jet language (which I don't know). This is why I said: "just to give you an idea"